# Oracle KPRB Driver: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified using OracleDriver.defaultConnection();

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

**Background:**

We are using Oracle SQL 12c Enterprise Edition. The Oracle SQL database is running locally on this machine and we are able to use "Oracle SQL Developer" to create tables and run queries.

**The Problem:**

When it come to connecting to the database in Java, we get invalid URL exceptions no matter what we try. There are a few types of "Drivers": thin, OCI, and the KPRB driver. It seems that the KPRB driver is what we should be using because it provides the fastest connection by taking advantage of the fact that the server is running on the same machine. For the specific driver, just purely guessing, we went with the ojdbc7.jar in the ..\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib folder.

The documentation we did find seemed to say that we don't need to specify a database name, or login information. This is an example of what we have tried:

> ```
>     OracleDataSource ods = null;
>     try {
>         ods = new OracleDataSource();
>     } catch (SQLException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
>     //ods.setUser("username");
>     //ods.setPassword("password");
>     ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:kprb:");       
>     //Connection conn = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
>     try {
>         Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
>     } catch (SQLException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> ```

We have tried all sorts of variations of this with the same error every time. Is there a sure-fire way to set up this connection correctly?

EDIT:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:453)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:317)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:241)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:184)
    at com.web.code.search.utilities.MyUtility.run(MyUtility.java:185)
    at com.web.code.search.controllers.MyController.init(MyController.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$2/2000502240.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Oracle KPRB Driver is server-side internal driver. Do you use it with java's programs stored in db?

Comment: I don't know about java's programs stored in db. I do know that we don't want to waste time connecting though a websocket or local port to localhost or 127.0.0.1 when we could instead connect the DB directly since it is stored and running locally on the same machine.

Comment: As Arkadiusz said: the internal driver can _only_ be used if your Java application is stored _inside_ the database and is executed by the JVM that is part of the database (which is typically a very old Java version). You can **not**  use it for "external" programs. The rest of the world is happy with connecting through TCP, so why to you think it won't be good enough for you?

Comment: Use google, search for **"Java stored procedures"**. In  case of 12c, Oracle uses JVM 1.6 to run the Java code. Beware this JVM in slightly modified and you might face some gotchas when running your code on this JVM.

Comment: PS: You can also use OCI driver, which can connect through SHM(shared memory). This will speedup round-trips between client and server. But **will not** speedup database connection creation - as this is very costly operation on DB server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run KPRB driver only on the DB server side by creating a wrapper for the corresponding Java function.

Please see below on how the InternalT2Driver.sql will look like.

```
rem Reads the content of the Java source from InternalT2Driver.java 
rem then compiles it 
connect hr/hr
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED InternalT2Driver_src AS
@ InternalT2Driver.java
/

show error

rem A wrapper (a.k.a. Call Spec), to invoke Java
rem function in the database from SQL, PL/SQL, and client applications
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE InternalT2Driver_proc AS 
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'InternalT2Driver.jrun ()';
/

rem Running the sample
connect hr/hr
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 10000 
CALL dbms_java.set_output (10000);

execute InternalT2Driver_proc;
```

You can define getting a DB connection by specifying the URL (jdbc:oracle:kprb:@) and perform any DB operations.

Please refer to the JDBC Developers guide (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/toc.htm) for more details.